# MenuBar using Javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am trying to make a horizontal menu bar using CSS and Javascript.
When clicked, I want the menu item to background to turn black.
Here is a part of HTML code-

```
<ul id="top_menu">
                    <li onclick="arrow(this)"><a href="#">item no 1</a></li>
                    <li onclick="arrow(this)"><a href="#">item no 2</a></li>
                    <li onclick="arrow(this)"><a href="#">item no 3</a></li>
                    <li onclick="arrow(this)"><a href="#">item no 4</a></li>
                    <li onclick="arrow(this)"><a href="#">item no 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript part-

```
function arrow(x){
                x.style.background="#000000";
            }
```

Now when someone clicks on the menu, the background turns black.The problem is when any other item is selected(clicked) the previous selected item doesn't goes back to its original background color.
How should I implement this feature?
Thanks!

Comment: Reset the background of ALL menu items, and THEN change the one that was clicked.

Comment: @Blazemonger if my list is under ul tags of id list1 then should this work document.getElementById("list").reset();?

Comment: No, `reset()` is for forms. You need to "reset" the color of the list items using some code of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways... This one is easiest to me:

```
function arrow(x){


    var ul = document.getElementById('top_menu');

list=ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){

        if(list[i]!==x){        
list[i].style.background="#ffffff";  
        }
        else {
             list[i].style.background="#000000";
        }
    }



            }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ag9L09sb/1/